# PHP Garbage Collector Keeps Removing My Sessions

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.5

**The Problem:**

I have a website that uses PHP sessions to allow users to log in. It works fine. But the session expires too soon that 1 minute of inactivity will log out the user.

**My Environment:**

Php version: 7.1

Server: NGINX

Framework: CakePHP 3.5

**What I did so far?**

I did every single solution on the StackOverflow or any search result I get. I extended my session timeout both in php.ini and CakePHP configurations.

**The solution**

After 2 or 3 days of research, I found the solution. In my php.ini I found a configuration named `session.gc_probability` and I put value `0` for that. Now my sessions never get expired except if the user logs out intentionally.

**And now my current problem is**, I don't want my `session.gc_probability` configuration to be zero as it will not collect any garbage (Not really sure about this. Please correct me if this information is wrong.). And this will cause the sessions to remain for month or years which a real GARBAGE for the server.

I got the idea of giving `session.gc_probability` zero value from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability)

```
session.gc_divisor coupled with session.gc_probability defines the 
probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on 
every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using 
gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that 
the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to 
100.
```

What is exactly wrong with my configurations? What causes the garbage collection to remove my sessions that soon? `session.gc_probability` was 1 and `session.gc_divisor` was 1000. I think a process with 1/1000 probability should not start every 1 or 2 minutes.

Comment: What's your `Session.handler`?

Comment: What's gc_maxlifetime set to?  Garbage collection likely isn't the problem, just a side effect.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález its the default php session handler. Shouldn't that be "file"?

Comment: @Devon I will get back to you in a minute

Comment: @Devon After you asked that I remember it was initially 1440 (seconds) and I have edited to 1440000 at that time and forgot. Do you think this was the problem? Because 1440/60 is 24 minutes. But my sessions were expiring in one or two minutes.

Comment: Well, garbage collection shouldn't have started on any session until it has been stale for 1440 (or gc_maxlifetime) seconds.  So 1-2 minutes on an active session shows me that something else is wrong on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What else do you think may cause this problem? should I put back 1440 instead of 1440000 or is it fine?

Comment: The `php` handler uses php.ini settings, what typically means that all PHP applications share the same session files (thus the "fastest" garbage collector wins). I normally prefer to use `cake` so it stores data inside my app's `tmp/sessions`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález is it a built-in handler or should I install?

Comment: @Devon Sorry i forgot to tag you :)

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I did that and i am now testing the results. I reverted all php.ini settings to defaults. If it works i will notify you :) thank you for your attention

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am now using "cake" handler and I think this solved my problem. It is not loggin me out. If you write an answer to this question containing the answer in detail I will confirm it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your follow-up comments your setting for `Session.handler` is `php`. The [Sessions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration) documentation explains:

> The built-in configurations are:
>
> - `php` - Saves sessions with the standard settings in your php.ini file.
> - `cake` - Saves sessions as files inside `tmp/sessions`. This is a good option when on hosts that don’t allow you to write outside your
>     own home dir.
>
> […]

The default php.ini setting for [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) depends on your PHP distribution (and it can be changed anyway) but it normally involves a shared data storage for all PHP applications that do not opt out. That means that the app with the shortest [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) is likely to remove session data from other apps.

Switching to `cake` should address that.

---

*A little follow-up about `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`. Setting them too aggressively will cause frequent garbage collection. That may harm performance but it won't cause premature data expiration.* On the other side, too loose values will still allow access to obsolete data.